# Can I use an animated gif in a feDisplacementMap filter?

Tags: svg

Can I use an animated gif in a feDisplacementMap filter?

I tried something like this, without any result:

```
<filter id="filter" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    
    <feImage xlink:href="animation.gif" result="gif" />
                                    
    <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="gif" scale="6" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"/>
    
</filter>
```

Comment: Actually you can! (in all but Safari) The gotcha is that the image file must be served from the same origin: https://jsfiddle.net/tm97pcdf/1/

Comment: @Kaiido That works great. You should probably add this as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, at least in Chrome and Firefox.

The gotcha in these browsers is that the image resource fetched from `<feImage>` must be served from the same origin.

Note that the [`crossorigin` attribute](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#element-attrdef-feimage-crossorigin) should have been able to help here, but currently no browser supports it on `<feImage>`, and while Chrome does support it on `<image>` and does support references to local elements in `<feImage>`, it will still block the filter when reaching the `<feDisplacementMap>` node.

```css
.p1 {
  filter: url(#filt-1);
}
.p2 {
  filter: url(#filt-2);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute">
  <!-- Using the <feImage> + crossorigin should have worked out of the box -->
  <filter id="filt-1">
    <feImage
      result="img"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/evjh08nnu0me4lo/banana.gif"
    />
    <feDisplacementMap
      scale="15"
      xChannelSelector="R"
      yChannelSelector="G"
      in2="img"
      in="SourceGraphic"
    />
  </filter>
  <!-- Using an intermediary <image> + crossorigin should also have worked -->
  <defs>
    <image
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      id="imgEl"
      width="500"
      height="50"
      href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/evjh08nnu0me4lo/banana.gif"
    />
  </defs>
  <filter id="filt-2">
    <feImage
      result="img"
      href="#imgEl"
    />
    <feDisplacementMap
      scale="15"
      xChannelSelector="R"
      yChannelSelector="G"
      in2="img"
      in="SourceGraphic"
    />
   </filter>
</svg>

<p class="p1">
  This paragraph uses the <code>&lt;feImage crossorigin></code> directly.
</p>
<p class="p2">
  This paragraph uses the <code>&lt;image></code> intermediary.
</p>
```

So this means you really have to serve it from the same origin and not "in a Same-Origin compliant way".

Since we can't host files from `https://stacksnippet.com` domain, for the following demo I'll fetch the resource as Blob and create local `blob:` URLs from it:

```js
// fetching as a Blob first to build a local URL
fetch("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/evjh08nnu0me4lo/banana.gif")
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob => document.querySelector("feImage").setAttribute("href", URL.createObjectURL(blob)))
```

```css
section { filter: url(#filter) }
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute">
  <filter id="filter">
    <feImage result="img" />
    <feDisplacementMap
      scale="15"
      xChannelSelector="R"
      yChannelSelector="G"
      in2="img"
      in="SourceGraphic"
    />
  </filter>
</svg>
<section>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id purus sit amet augue consequat volutpat. Ut sed lectus tellus. Vivamus viverra condimentum facilisis. Sed vestibulum, libero quis suscipit molestie, ex elit finibus ante, eleifend mollis nibh enim non sapien. Aliquam suscipit id risus a efficitur. Quisque ac mollis justo. Suspendisse laoreet dolor vitae nisi efficitur, id molestie lorem tristique. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc nec purus neque. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus lacus massa, placerat ac interdum vitae, gravida sed quam. Quisque non finibus mauris. Vivamus lacinia felis at est egestas, eu imperdiet mi convallis.
  </p><p>
  Mauris dignissim leo a erat dictum bibendum. Etiam viverra consequat quam, at volutpat justo vehicula nec. Donec lectus nisl, suscipit nec orci vel, sagittis mattis sem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Mauris elementum aliquam malesuada. Suspendisse cursus, leo sed pellentesque faucibus, nibh mauris euismod erat, sed porta odio lorem eu neque. In vehicula pretium sem, ac convallis ante pharetra sit amet.
  </p><p>
  Aliquam pretium mauris finibus pellentesque facilisis. Aliquam euismod accumsan maximus. Praesent in leo odio. Vestibulum accumsan, nibh sit amet tempus dapibus, tortor elit rhoncus nibh, at aliquet enim orci finibus lectus. Praesent varius velit tellus, sit amet viverra erat ultricies ac. Sed nec lorem maximus, pharetra nisl ac, scelerisque arcu. Proin pellentesque at libero at ultricies. Pellentesque sed commodo turpis. Ut suscipit lacus ac quam tristique laoreet ut in sapien.
  </p><p>
  Vivamus tempus dapibus odio, in pharetra ligula. Aenean iaculis finibus gravida. Sed auctor eget ante sed tincidunt. Nullam varius vel tortor ut venenatis. In sit amet pulvinar sem. Vestibulum ex elit, interdum id erat in, aliquam vestibulum nunc. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras sagittis scelerisque bibendum. Pellentesque diam ante, blandit imperdiet ultricies sit amet, tincidunt eu mi. Maecenas ac semper lacus. Etiam eu ex quis nibh faucibus egestas. Sed hendrerit vehicula elit, eget pretium ex mollis suscipit.
  </p><p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae pharetra est. Integer pretium, augue auctor rhoncus elementum, tortor orci laoreet nunc, eget aliquam mauris mi vel mauris. Sed hendrerit lorem nisi, nec commodo nulla suscipit in. Nulla molestie pretium consequat. Cras ac elementum magna. Sed suscipit nibh eu nibh luctus volutpat. Sed pellentesque mauris in erat mattis dictum. 
  </p>
</section>
```

Now beware that Safari will only render the first frame of the animated gif. I couldn't find a workaround to make it use the other frames.